# Removing letters from words within a file C - problematic sign

Tags: c, file, copy, std, ctype

to be precise, I'm trying to copy from file A to file B, every word that DOES NOT have both letters 'e' and 't' in them (the, peter, etc), the program works fine, but at the end of the outfile I'm getting a weird sign.

```
Input: What says Lucentio to this shame of ours?
Output: What says  to this shame of ours?˙
```

(Can u see the character `˙`?)

I dont want it, I have no idea whats that, but its not EOF, i tried to declude it from copying and it does not work. I require some help here.

Code:

```
char signHold[1];

int main(int *argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE* infile;
    FILE* outfile;

    char* string = NULL;
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf(stderr,"Error: Improper number of arguments");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    remove(argv[2]);
    infile = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    while(feof(infile) == 0)
    {
        string = getWord(infile);
        if(checkDenied(string))
        addToFile(outfile, argv[2], string);

        addToFile(outfile, argv[2], signHold);
    }
    fclose(infile);
    free(string);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

char* getWord(FILE* ptr)
{
    char* tempString;
    size_t memSize = 0;
    int c;

    tempString = expandRealloc(NULL,sizeof(char));
    while(c = fgetc(ptr))
    {
        if(isalpha(c) != 0)
        {
            tempString = expandRealloc(tempString, (memSize+1)*sizeof(char)+1);
            tempString[memSize] = c;
            memSize++;
        }
        else
        {
            signHold[0] = c;
            break;
        }
    }
    tempString[memSize] = '\0';
    return tempString;
}

short int checkDenied(const char* str)
{
    int i;

    i = strspn("e", str);

    if(i >= 1)
    {
        i = strspn("t", str);
        if(i >= 1)
        {
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

short int addToFile(FILE* ptr, char* directory, char* text)
{
    ptr = fopen(directory,"a+");
    fprintf(ptr,"%s", text);
    fclose(ptr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why? This is going to be heavily I/O bound, so using C gains nothing over, say, AWK, in which it's trivial.

Comment: I'm a Computer Science student, and I'm trying to learn C.. What AWK has to do with this? ~.~

Comment: Was it assigned as homework, or just your own idea of something to do? If it's homework, it should probably be tagged as such. Otherwise, I'd advise picking something else that's at least reasonably suited to the things C does well.

Comment: Side note: You may want to use [strchr](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strchr/) instead of `strspn`.

Comment: Also, include the code for `addToFile`

Comment: Your `while( !feof(fp))` usage is terribly wrong. Much easyer is to just read a character using fgetc(), and comparing every returned int-value with EOF.

Comment: Another side note: instead of reopening the file for every word, try opening it once in the beginning and close it before quitting. Your way runs many many expensive and useless operations.

Comment: addToFile added, althou I dont see how it could be relevant to the topic, its just a normal append function. No, it is not homework, I'm learning to an exam from C, simple. Also can I ask the people to stay on topic? I'm curious why this sign is there, and whats that, and how to declude it, rather than curious on how you would do the code. So please.

Comment: Also what's `int *argc`?

Comment: Why not rewrite the program as a state machine, you only need a buffer for the current word, + its length, + the state (there are only four states needed, plus maybe EOF)

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are assuming `fgetc` returns `0` on end of file, but that is not true. It returns `EOF`. Perhaps you are reading the `EOF`, assigning it to a character, that is `signHold[0]` (which could result in anything since `EOF` doesn't fit in `char`)

You then proceed to print `signHold` which contains a random character followed by **who knows what** since the string is not NUL-terminated (its size is 1 and its first character isn't '`\0'`. That is, you are printing anything that could happen to be after `signHold`. (This is also undefined behavior by the way).

Comment: Could u point me the line where I assume fgetc returns 0? Also termination of the signhold[0] is not the issue, if i do:         if(signHold[0] == '˙') and declude it like that, the char does not appear, which shows that the char is not signHold[495964] but signHold[0].

Comment: I dont assume anything in this line, I'm just taking the character using fgetc, and eof is being checked in main using feof() >.>

Comment: @PiotrJerzyMamenas, you have put it in a while loop. This means your loop will stop when `c = fgetc(ptr)` is zero. When reading `EOF`, it is **not** zero. Therefore you go in the loop, and check if `isalpha(c)` is true, which is not. You then store it in `signhold[0]` and break. Also, `˙` is not an ASCII character. This means that whatever that got in `c` from `EOF` is being interpreted as that character. Since what you do is undefined behavior, anything could happen. Conversion of `EOF` to `char` could be different from `'˙'`.

Comment: else
        {
            signHold[0] = c;
            break;
        }

Comment: Hope the following piece explains in detail that I'm not doing what you just said. The loop is being cancelled the first instance it meets a non-alpha value such as EOF/?/!/./: etc ~.~, I do however appriaciae the fact of point me that the sign is not a ASCII value, this is of great help.

Comment: @PiotrJerzyMamenas, yes. But you store it in `signHold[0]` and later print it: `addToFile(outfile, argv[2], signHold);`

Comment: if(signHold[0] != '˙')
        {
            addToFile(outfile, argv[2], signHold);
        } thats the condition i use for checking, it works so far, what would u suggest to fix the issue without discluding it like that?

Comment: Like I told you, `signHold[0] = EOF` could be anything. `'˙'` is evaluated by the C compiler and `c = EOF` at run-time. These values could be different. Like I said, `˙` is not an ASCII character and you can't use it like `'˙'`. This is undefined behavior. If [demons fly out of your nose](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/comp.std.c/ycpVKxTZkgw/S2hHdTbv4d8J) you shouldn't be surprised.

Comment: What you _could_ do is `if (feof(infile) == 0) { addToFile(outfile, argv[2], signHold); }`

Comment: @PiotrJerzyMamenas The condition of the loop should be `while((c = fgetc(ptr)) != EOF)`, so you don't store `EOF` in `signHold[0]`. Also, `signHold` **must** have space for the 0-terminator. Furthermore, you leak memory, since `string` gets a newly allocated piece of memory for every word, but only the last is `free`d.

Answer (score 0):

This is the statemachine. Making it use a variable sized buffer is left an exercise to the reader ;-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *infile;
    FILE *outfile;

    char buff[100];
    size_t len,idx;
    int ch, state;

    if(argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: Improper number of arguments");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    infile = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    outfile = fopen(argv[2],"w");

    len = 0;
    for (state=0; state >= 0; ) {
        ch = fgetc(infile);
        if (isalpha(ch)) {
            if (ch == 'e') state |= 1;
            else if (ch == 't') state |= 2;
            if (state != 3) buff[len++] = ch;
            continue;
        }
    /* no character, this must be the end of a word. */
        if (state != 3) for(idx=0; idx < len; idx++ ) {
            fputc(buff[idx], outfile);
            }
        if (ch == EOF) {state = -1; continue;}
        fputc(ch, outfile);
        len = 0; state = 0;
        }
    fclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is junk memory stored at signHold[1].  You only allow 1 character and do not NUL terminate it.  This means when you write out the question mark it also writes out any memory after it that is before the first '\0'.